# How to change a DependencyProperty value from another one in UWP, FrameworkPropertyMetadata not being available

Tags: c#, uwp, dependency-properties

I'm creating a XAML Custom Control in a UWP project and I was going to implement the same pattern I already found usable in WPF applications, to edit control's properties all at once when a main DependencyProperty changes.

In the sample code below I sow how I change a `SolidColorBrush` dp (called "ColorBrush") when a `Color` dp (named "Color") is changed by an external user.

In WPF, this was the pattern I implemented (correctly working):

```
public partial class ColorViewer : UserControl
{

    // .ctor and other functions

    public Color Color
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(ColorProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ColorProperty, value);
        }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Color", typeof(Color), typeof(ColorViewer), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnColorChanged));



    public SolidColorBrush ColorBrush
    {
        get { return (SolidColorBrush)GetValue(ColorBrushProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColorBrushProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColorBrushProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ColorBrush", typeof(SolidColorBrush), typeof(ColorViewer), null);


    private static void OnColorChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var c = (Color) e.NewValue;

        ColorViewer view = source as ColorViewer;
        view.UpdateColorProperties(c);
    }

    private void UpdateColorProperties(Color c)
    {
        ColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(c);

        // Many other things...
    }
 }
```

In particular, I passed a **`FrameWorkPropertyMetadata`** (with a method as its parameter) to the setting "Color" dp.

**With my big (and sad) surprise, I found that `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` isn't available in the UWP platform!**

How can I get the same result in UWP?

Thanks for your attention.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesnt have that because imho its more of an bloat than anything,
Uwp has a much simpler `ProperyMetadata` class that allows you to set the default value of the dp and if you want to go deeper it also allows you to set a CallBack that is invoked on a value change.

The Last argument in that `.Register()` function is where `ProperyMetadata` goes.

On a side note, Brushes types like a `SolidColorBrush`dp will be nicely and automatically grouped in the **Brush** group on the Properties pane, misc types of dp will be often listed under the **Common** group